# List in C# not rendered as array using MongoDB official client

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, nosql

I am using MongoDB with ASP.NET and the official driver from 10gen.  My problems is with how my class is rendered as documents (serialized).

I have a class called 'box', and another class calls 'items'.

Items appear in the class as follows:

```
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    [BsonElementAttribute("items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Each items have several properties assigned to it in its own class.

When I view the JSON document that was inserted into Mongo, I see it like this:

```
Items: {
   "0": {
      "_id": ObjectId("33423423423434343434"),
       "name": "Item1"
     },
}
```

However, I don't want it to appear like that, but appear as an array like this:

```
Items: [
    {
       "_id": ObjectId("34234234234234234"),
       "name": "some name",
    },
   {
       "_id": ObjectId("34234234234234234"),
       "name": "some name",
    }
]
```

Adding items in the code behind:

```
     List<Item> theItems = new List<Item>();
        Item singleitem = new Item{
           Title = "single item one"
        };

    theItems.Add(singleitem);
    theItems.Add(singleitem);

    var box= new Box
    {
        IsPublic = true,
        Items = theItems
    };

    SafeModeResult sf = collectionBoxes.Insert(box);
```

So the items will appear as an array. How can I change my code to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you write how do you add the list of items to the database?

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?